# Calling Certain Methods

Tags: java, methods

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HW {

public static void main(String[] args){
    while (retry == true){
        getGuess();
        getBet(balance);
        checkGuess(getGuess());
        updateBal(guessResult, betParsed);
        goAgain(balance);
    }
}


public static String getGuess(){
    //Guess input
    System.out.println("Guess: (H/T");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean validInput = false;
    String guess = null;
    while (validInput == false){
        guess = in.next(); 
        if (guess.equals("H") || guess.equals("T")){
            validInput = true;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input: " + guess);
        }
    }
    return guess;
}

public static boolean checkGuess(String sideGuess){
    //Checks if the side is correct
    double num = Math.round(Math.random());
    boolean guessResult;
    if (num == 0 && sideGuess.equals("H")){
        System.out.println("Correct. The side was: H");
        guessResult = true;
        return true;
    } else if (num == 1 && sideGuess.equals("T")){
        System.out.println("Correct. The side was: T");
        guessResult = true;
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect.");
        guessResult = false;
        return false;
    }
}

public static double getBet(double balance){
    //Retrieves a bet from the user
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String betInput = null;
    double betParsed = 0;
    boolean validInput = false;
    while (validInput == false){
        betInput = in.next();
        try {
            betParsed = Double.parseDouble(betInput);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invlaid Input: " + betInput);
        }
        if (betParsed > balance || betParsed < 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input! You have: $" + balance);
        } else {
            validInput = true;
        }
    }
    return betParsed;
}

public static double updateBal(boolean checkGuess, double getBet){
    //Updates the balance based on the bet
    double balance = 0;
    if (checkGuess == true){
        balance = balance + getBet * 2;
        System.out.println("Your balance is now: $" + balance);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your balance is now: $" + balance);
        balance = balance - getBet;
    }
    return balance;
}

public static boolean goAgain(double balance){
    //Determines if new play is needed
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean validInput = false;
    String goAgainInput = null;
    boolean retry;
    while (validInput == false){
        System.out.println("Go again? (Y/N)");
        goAgainInput = in.next();
        if (goAgainInput.equals("Y") || goAgainInput.equals("N")){
            validInput = true;          
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input: " + goAgainInput);
        }
    }
    if (goAgainInput.equals("Y")){
        retry = true;
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("You ended with: $" + balance);
        retry = false;
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Edited the code.

I'm trying to pass some defined variables into some of the methods, but it seems that I can't use them?

How can I fix this?

It seems they are not "local", which I cannot understand as they are defined in the methods.
I must be under thinking it.

Comment: First and foremost: Your main method can only have one parameter, the String array called args (or call it anything you want), but it can't have two parameters. Next if you have any other errors after this is fixed, you'd better post them here. Also, it looks as though your coding without an IDE and that if so, you're not compiling or testing your code often, which is a big problem. If you can't use an IDE that immediately warns you of compilation errors, you must compile and test your code often, and fix any and all errors before trying to add more code.\

Comment: OK, that works. What I try to do is to create a skeleton program first, one with empty method bodies, other than debug println statements, and then try to run my program often, filling in each method body and testing it.

Comment: How would I go about passing goAgain to the main method?

Comment: You need to assign the result returned by the `goAgain()` method to a boolean variable that the while loop uses. And don't give your variables the same names as your methods as that will confuse.

Answer (score 4):

The `main()` method should look like this, with only *one* parameter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

And for the second issue, `updateBal()` receives *two* parameters, but you're passing none. So the compiler is correctly complaining that you should pass them, according to what you want to do:

```
updateBal(false, 0); // pass the right values
```

Regarding the passing of parameters to the method, this is wrong:

```
getBet(balance);
checkGuess(getGuess());
updateBal(guessResult, betParsed);
```

You see, the variables `guessResult` and `betParsed` are *local* to the methods in which they were defined, you can't use them outside. And the methods return a value, which gets lost, because you're not using or storing it. Both problems have a simple solution - declare new variables local to the method:

```
double betParsed = getBet(balance);
boolean guessResult = checkGuess(getGuess());
updateBal(guessResult, betParsed);
```

Again, the same problem is here, in the main loop:

```
boolean retry = true;
while (retry) {
    // ...
    retry = goAgain(balance);
}
```

Bottom line: you *must* do something with the value returned by methods, and the variables declared inside a method will *not* be visible outside them.

Comment: What I want to pass to it is the output of checkGuess, not a constant value. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @ModifyYou then store the value returned by `checkGuess` in a local variable, and pass the variable.

Comment: Updated the OP with my problem.

Comment: @ModifyYou is as I told you above: you must use local variables. I edited my answer, I hope this gets accepted ;)

Comment: Alright, that worked, thanks. Last thing is I can't figure how to get the "retry" variable for the while loop in the main method. Any ideas?

Comment: @ModifyYou same thing - before the loop do this: `boolean retry = true;` and inside the loop do this: `retry = goAgain(balance);`

Comment: ALright, sorry for this long comment conversation... Last question (I hope) It jumps straight to "Your balance is $100." Any ideas why it does this?

Comment: @ModifyYou well it seems that `checkGuess()` is always returning `true`. Check it, and also check that the value returned by `getGuess()` is correct - use a debugger if needed. I'll leave it up to you.